# Alterar função do onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

Pessoal estou com uma dúvida.

Tenho um botão:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" onclick="vincularContato($(this))"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>
```

E duas funções, uma vincularContato e outra removerContato passando o próprio botão como parâmetro:

```
function removerContato(botao) {

    var tempIdContato = botao.closest("tr")
                             .find(".idContato")
                             .text();

    botao.removeClass('btn-danger');
    botao.addClass('btn-success');
    botao.html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>');
    //    botao.prop('onclick', null).off('click');
    //    botao.prop('onclick', vincularContato(botao)).off('click');

}

function vincularContato(botao) {

    var tempIdContato = botao.closest("tr")
                             .find(".idContato")
                             .text();

    botao.removeClass('btn-success');
    botao.addClass('btn-danger');
    botao.html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>');
    //    botao.prop('onclick', null).off('click');
    //    botao.prop('onclick', removerContato(botao)).off('click');

}
```

O que eu preciso é alterar a função do onclick do meu botão sempre que for clicado, alternando de uma função para outra.

O botão está trocando o span e a classe, mas não consigo mudar o onclick.

Comentei um dos meus testes, fiz alguns outros modos mas sem sucesso.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma muito simples de resolver isso é utilizar o método `.attr()` em cada função, trocando o `onclick`:

## Com jQuery

```js
function removerContato(botao) {
  alert("vincularContato");
  botao.attr('onclick', 'vincularContato($(this));');
}

function vincularContato(botao) {
  alert("removerContato");
  botao.attr('onclick', 'removerContato($(this));');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" onclick="removerContato($(this))" value="Clique aqui">
```

## Sem jQuery

```js
function removerContato(botao) {
  alert("função removerContato");
  botao.setAttribute("onclick","vincularContato(this);");
}

function vincularContato(botao) {
  alert("função vincularContato");
  botao.setAttribute("onclick","removerContato(this);");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="vincularContato(this)" value="Clique aqui">
```

Comment: Vou acrescentar meus 2 cents na sua resposta, por que era exatamente o que iria responder, só que usando js puro, sem jQuery :)

Comment: Caso se sinta incomodado com as alterações feitas, pode [reverter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/229023/revisions) a resposta para sua resposta original

Comment: agora sim tá bonito :)

Answer (score 2):

Particularmente acho que é melhor você ter dois botões, um pra cada ação, e no momento que você clicar em um, oculta o outro, e assim sucessivamente, veja no exemplo:

- `.on('click', function () { ... }`: atribui o evento `click` ao botão assim que ele for renderizado no HTML.
- `.toggle()`: Alterna a visibilidade do elemento, se estiver visível oculta e se estiver oculto torna-o visível.
- `.show()`: Altera a visibilidade do elemento para visível.

```js
$('#botao1').on('click', function() {
  console.log('Evento 1');
  $(this).toggle();
  $('#botao2').show();
});

$('#botao2').on('click', function() {
  console.log('Evento 2');
  $(this).toggle();
  $('#botao1').show();
});
```

```css
#botao2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="botao1">Ação 1</button>
<button id="botao2">Ação 2</button>
```

Comment: ou talvez ele possa criar uma variavel e ir incrementando ela e caso a variavel % 2 retorne 1 ele faz uma coisa senao faz outra.

Comment: Boa ideia Pedro, amanhã irei fazer isso mesmo, não tinha pensado nisso! Haha... Valeu

Comment: Pode ser feito sim @ViniciusPuttiMorais, porém, você mesmo está dizendo que terá um trabalho "extra" a ser feito `criar uma variavel e ir incrementando ela`. Concorda?

Comment: realmente, na verdade depende do gosto.

Answer (score 2):

Algo como:

```
var aux = true;
function acaoContato(botao) {
    aux ? removerContato(botao) : vincularContato(botao);
}
```

Ao final de cada uma das funções vc realiza a troca de estado do aux, e no botão chama o acaoContato.

Ou pode colocar as ações todas dentro da mesma função:

```
var aux = true;
function acaoContato(botao) {
    aux ? {
        // Conteúdo do removerContato
    } : {
        // Conteúdo do vincularContato
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Um dos truques para que isso funcione é a a função innerHTML que executa uma troca de conteúdo em uma tag “div” especificada.

## Assim com javascript puro:

```js
function removerContato(botao) {

   console.log("clicou na função removerContato");
    
   document.getElementById("dibotao").innerHTML =('<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" onclick="vincularContato(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">Vincular</span></button>');

}

function vincularContato(botao) {

   console.log("clicou na função vincularContato");

   document.getElementById("dibotao").innerHTML =('<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" onclick="removerContato(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">Remover</span></button>');

}
```

```html
<div id="dibotao"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" onclick="vincularContato(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">Vincular</span></button></div>
```

## Assim com jquery

> O método .html() substitui conteúdo

```js
function removerContato(botao) {
  console.log("clicou na função removerContato");
  botao.parent().html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" onclick="vincularContato($(this))"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">Vincular</span></button>');

}

function vincularContato(botao) {
  console.log("clicou na função vincularContato");
  botao.parent().html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" onclick="removerContato($(this))"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">Remover</span></button>');

  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dibotao"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" onclick="vincularContato($(this))"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">Vincular</span></button></div>
```

Comment: @MarceloBoni, xuxu beleza

Answer (score 2):

Particularmente procuro escrever códigos reutilizáveis, otimizados e de fácil manutenção (infelizmente nem sempre é possível!). Os benefícios são óbvios: você pode simplesmente copiar e colar em qualquer lugar que ele funcionará. Claro que devemos considerar as dependências, etc.

**As soluções aqui citadas são válidas**, porém sugiro que você crie um plugin pra resolver seu problema, algo simples que cuide apenas da UI e seja flexível o suficiente para você aplicar em diferentes contextos.

Escrevi rápidamente, certamente você pode melhorar.

Considere:

- Js é uma linguagem funcional, aproveite;
- Sempre que possível separe a logica da aplicação;
- Códigos menores e independentes são mais fáceis de testar e manter;
- Programe coisas que você pode reutilizar em outros projetos;

```js
/*

index.js

Considerando que você importou o plugin, basta iniciar. Você pode 
passar duas funções que serão executadas quando tiver alteração 
no status. O contexto do this é o $(this), ou seja o 
próprio elemento,dessa forma você pode recuperar atributos, ou 
fazer qualquer coisa com o botão...
*/

$(function(){
  $('.contact').statusButton({
    enabled: function() {
      console.log('ENABLED', this.data('contact'));
    },
    disabled: function() {
      console.log('DISABLED', this.data('contact'));
    }
  });
});




/*

status-button.js

*/

(function($) {

  /**
  * statusButton
  * @param Object options
  */
  $.fn.statusButton = function(options) {


    /**
    * settings
    */
    var settings = $.extend({
      template: {
        add: {
          'class': 'btn-success',
          'icon': 'glyphicon-ok',
        },
        remove: {
          'class': 'btn-danger',
          'icon': 'glyphicon-remove',
        },
      },
      enabled: function() {},
      disabled: function() {}
    }, options);


    /**
    * changeStatus
    */
    var changeStatus = {

      enabled: function($icon) {
        this.removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-success');
        this.find('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
      },

      disabled: function ($icon) {
        this.removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger');
        this.find('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
      }
    };


    /**
    * For each Element...
    */
    return this.each(function() {

      var status = $(this).data('status') || 'enabled';

      changeStatus[status].call($(this));

      $(this).click(function(){
        status = status === 'enabled' ? 'disabled' : 'enabled';
        changeStatus[status].call($(this));
        settings[status].call($(this));
      });
    })

  }

}(jQuery));
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<!--
index.html

Insira uma classe pra você usar no plugin. Além disso 
você pode usar o data-status="disabled" caso precise 
que inicie desabilitado.
-->

<button data-contact="100" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs contact">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
</button>

<button data-status="disabled" data-contact="321" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs contact">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
</button>


<button data-contact="123" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs contact">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
</button>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```